# How could Jiraya use sage mode by holding his hands?

Tags: naruto

So Naruto can enter sage mode in a matter of seconds but he has to be completely still. But Jiraya could use sage mode with only using his hands but it took him a long long time to achieve it..why the difference?

Answer (score 2):

You are not right with that Naruto can enter in sage mode in just matter of seconds, It also take time to gain sage chakra from nature for Naruto.

There are some condition to gain sage chakra from nature.

> In order to gather enough natural energy to initiate the
>   transformation into Sage Mode, the user must remain perfectly still.

To overcome this weekness, Jiraya use
[Sage Art: Amphibian Technique](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Sage_Art:_Amphibian_Technique), where one or more toads fuses with the user's shoulders and gather natural energy for them to use.

Where Naruto Use his shadow clone to gather nature energy and call back his clone to his original self to gain sage chakra. but there is limit of shadow clone he use is 5.

You can find more details [here](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Sage_Mode).

Comment: might want to add that the clasped hands for so long was a requirement for him to summon the 2 sage toads so that they could gather the sage chakra for him.

Comment: @Ryan I'd rather if you posted an answer which actually answers the question and not corrects just the mistaken assumption, i.e. The requirement for summoning the Great Toads (Though not explained why). Also to add on it, later he could just use Kurama to mould Sage mode Chakra, so doesn't need the amphibious technique.

Comment: @Arcane I don't see a real reason to post an answer that is this answer reworded plus 2 sentences. Besides, everything I would add is already in the links in the answer, I just recommended the most important one was included in the answer instead of by proxy through a source.

Comment: @Ryan I am mostly opposed to the "Fastest Gun Policy" on the SE Sites. Most of the information that we put in our answer is mostly ALWAYS on Wiki sites. The trick to a good answer is finding out the correct information and verifying first hand it is indeed correct. The answer above doesn't answer the OP's question, but a seperate question, example why does Jiraiya summon toads while naruto doesn't etc. However, I leave this to your personal discretion. Cheers~

Comment: @Arcane You are right most of information that we put in our answer is mostly in wiki sites, but I tried to put points which I thought is important and answered the question in more details explaining other things which might not relevant to question is no good & writing my theories without any reference is not policy of SE. & What if wiki site contain most of the information, I think no mater how many time you read one book you will find new things every time you read it again. Anyway this is my thought & everyone else has different. :)

Comment: @Ryan I think clasped hands are like hand signs for sage mode. & as we know Jiraraya didn't mastered sage Jutsu so he miight need to do hand sign as in ninja world some ninja need to use hand sign to perform jutsu and some not, depends on their individual skills( this is just what i think) & keep taking nature chakra in his body he needed to summon those two toads which is not possible in case of Naruto because of Kurama and Naruto come up with his own solution for that with shadow clones.

Comment: @VishalTarkar They are not. As explicitly told in the Amphibian technique. Shima and Fukasaku are the ones who gather sage mode chakra. It works because they dont move while on Jiraya's shoulders, and thanks to the merging process, can give him senjutsu chakra. "This also allows Fukasaku and Shima to continuously gather natural energy for Jiraiya, as he cannot do so himself while on the move"